# How to click on icons on Home Screen using automation script execution using Katalon Studio?

Tags: automated-tests, android-testing, katalon-studio

I'm trying to click on an app icon which is on Home screen of an android moblie using Katalon Studio. I've taken the xpath of the app icon using its name/title/ID and its not finding the object while running the script.

Comment: Please, share your code trials and any error messages you might have.

Comment: Be sure that the icon is not into a frame